# Need a estimate for the norm in $H^{-1}(\Omega)-$dual space of $H_0^1(\Omega)$!

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^N, N\geq 2$.

Let $v\in H^{-1}(\Omega)$-dual space of $H_0^1(\Omega)$ and I want to find the assumptions on $u\in X, (X=?)$ such that the following inequality holds:

$$\|uv\|_{H^{-1}(\Omega)}\leq \|u\|_{X}\|v\|_{H^{-1}(\Omega)}$$

Comment: possible duplicate:   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1093112/related-with-norm-in-h-1?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

It is sufficient to require $u\in W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)\cap H^1_0(\Omega)$. Suppose this. Take $v\in H^{-1}(\Omega)$ and $w\in H^1(\Omega)$.

The notation $uv$ is kind of sloppy, I guess you meant something like
$$
(uv)(w) := v(uw) \quad w\in H^1_0(\Omega).
$$
Then
$$
|uv(w)| = |v(uw)| \le \|v\|_{H^{-1}} \|uw\|_{H^1(\Omega)} \le \|v\|_{H^{-1}}
( \|u\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}\|\nabla w\|_{L^2(\Omega)} + \|\nabla u\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}\| w\|_{L^2(\Omega)} )
\le 2\|v\|_{H^{-1}} \|u\|_{W^{1,\infty}} \|w\|_{H^1}.
$$
This proves, that the mapping $w\mapsto v(uw)$ is bounded.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @lamtran if the answer is correct and help you to solve your problem, then you should consider to up-vote and accept it. :)